# What is this dot appearing in the middle of proofs?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

In G.H. Hardy's 6th edition of *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, this dot appears in some proofs. For example, on page 2,

$$b\mid a \;.\; c\mid b \implies c\mid a$$

What is the dot on the left hand side of the arrow?

Comment: most likely means and. I have an earlier edition, let me look.

Comment: It appears to be a shorthand for this author used similarly to an "and" as in both $b\mid a$ and $c\mid b$ are simultaneously true implies that $c\mid a$ is true.  I prefer using an ampersand or a shorthand ampersand.

Comment: It denotes the logical AND (more commonly denoted by $\land$ in set theory)

Comment: I suspected a logical AND, but could not find anything in either the index or wikipedia. @JMoravitz, if you post the answer, I can accept!

Comment: It is equivalent to $,$ (comma), which in turn is equivalent to $\text{AND}$. For example: $x,y>0; c\mid a,b; b\mid a,c\mid b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the section *REMARKS ON NOTATION* right at the beginning of the book we find:

> and
>   \begin{align*}
> b\,|\,a \,.\,c\,|\,b\ \rightarrow\ c\,|\,a\qquad (p.1)
> \end{align*}
>   means 'if $b$ divides $a$ and $c$ divides $b$ then $c$ divides $a$'.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like my copy doesn't have this entry in the remarks. Which edition did you use to look this up?

Comment: @ChazBiroan: You're welcome. I also have the $6$th edition. You can find this section right before the table of contents.